# Jquery UI modal confirmation buttons not rendering HTML correctly, missing classes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

Having some trouble with my jQuery UI setup with bootstrap. For some reason when I do a dialog box jQuery is not adding the class "ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" to my buttons as it should. I was wondering if anybody has had a similar issue occur. The modal box is working correctly otherwise.

[JqueryUI example](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

What is being generated for their example:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
      <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
         <span class="ui-button-text">Delete all items</span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
       <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
       </button>
</div>
```

I am doing the exact same code from that example, but for some reason on my end it is only generating the following HTML:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
  <button> type="button">Ok</button>
  <button type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some jquery code you are trying to implement for jquery modal.